# What would astronauts see if they were in an Earth Moon L1 Lissajous orbit?

Tags: orbit, crewed-spaceflight

Would they be moving fast enough that the change of their position relative to the Earth and the Moon would be perceptible? Or would that change be too slow to notice moment by moment?

I take it as they continued around the orbit the field of stars they were looking at through their front windows would change.  How quickly would that change be?  Would the rate of change vary as they completed a full orbit?